# Поменять иконку приложения в заголовке окна java в intellej idea

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

Подскажите, как изменить стандартную иконку приложения, которая отображается у формы в заголовке? 
Файл с изображением лежит по пути: ..\TimeCheckJavaProject\out\production\JavaFxApplication\sample\icon.ico

Пытался делать так

```
Stage window;
window = primaryStage;
window.getIcons().add(new Image("file:icon.ico"));
```

Но он сыплет кучу ошибок

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.addTextRun(PrismTextLayout.java:755)
>       at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.addTextRun(GlyphLayout.java:140)
>       at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(GlyphLayout.java:210)
>       at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:770)
>       at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1021)
>       at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:223)
>       at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:246)
>       at javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Text.java:358)
>       at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_computeGeomBounds(Text.java:1168)
>       at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
>       at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
>       at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
>       at javafx.scene.Node$MiscProperties$2.computeBounds(Node.java:6472)
>       at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9306)
>       at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9276)
>       at javafx.scene.Node.getBoundsInLocal(Node.java:3156)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin$ContentView.layoutChildren(TextAreaSkin.java:207)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
>       at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Попробуйте так: `new Image(ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icon.ico"))`. При этом положите картинку в корень папки с `.java` файлами. То бишь рядом с пакетом `sample`

Comment: @Tsyklop, не распознается ClassName. Если заменить его, допустим, на Main (в этом классе код пишется), то ошибки нет, но и иконка не меняется. Скрин расположения файла icon.ico https://ibb.co/mZzR0U

Comment: `ClassName` это название Вашего класса. Значит файл не найден. поиграйтесь с путем к файлу. Просто в приложения структура иная. Если сделаете у себя проект с поддержкой `maven` то появиться папка `resources` где такие файлы располагаются и легко находятся в `java` коде

Comment: @Tsyklop, а если указать полный путь к изображению? Я так сделал, но ошибка теперь "Input stream must not be null"

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX считает путь относительно папки src
Соответственно, если нам нужно обратиться в папку которая на одном уровне с src, то путь будет выглядеть так "file:./folder/icon.png"